# Panic Button for Website using the ESC button

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am using wordpress on a dev site here: http://b67.3d8.myftpupload.com/ 
I'd like to add a panic button like I found here: https://github.com/TodayDesign/panic-button

When I download their software and use the test page I can use the ESC button but in WP it doesn't work. Button works fine.

I have basically just added their code (and changed the CSS) but something isn't correct with WP:

```
             <!-- begin panic button -->
                <div id="panic-container" class="panic-button">
                    <span class="panic-button__text">Protect yourself online.</span>
                    <a class="panic-button__link"
                        href="https://www.domesticshelters.org/safe-surfing"
                        >
                        Learn how to hide your browsing history.
                    </a>
                    <a id="panic-button" class="panic-button__button"
                        href="https://www.weather.com" 
                        >
                        <span class="panic-button__icon">&times;</span>
                        Quick exit (ESC)
                    </a>
                </div>
                <link rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/studiothick/panic-button/v1.0.4/dist/panic.css" />
                <script async src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/studiothick/panic-button/v1.0.4/dist/panic.min.js"></script>
              <!-- end panic button -->
```

Comment: Any javascript console errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using the latest version of the panic.js plugin, seen here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/studiothick/panic-button/v1.2.0/dist/panic.min.js

Comment: Glad to hear it!